# Normative theories of morality that are designed to help adherents improve their genetical success by means of doing the right thing

Tags: ethics, reference-request

Is there a school of thought in moral philosophy which holds that

> Moral advice that runs contrary to a person's genetical interests is essentially a waste of time; because, in the long-term, people will genetically evolve to be disposed to rejecting that advice.

?

Furthermore, I'm interested in normative theories of morality that are designed to help adherents improve their genetical success by means of doing the right thing.

Comment: The naturalistic fallacy is the idea that what is found in nature is good. Why there is homosexuality in animal kingdom?  If birds and beasts engage in adultery, infanticide, cannibalism, it must be OK. Can someone say that humans cannot harbor desires to kill, rape, lie, or steal because they are unnatural?

Comment: Well, I'm not claiming that everything natural is good. I am asking for a reference.

Comment: Observation: Social Darwinism is an ideology that seeks to apply biological of evolutionary theory to sociology and politics. But Darwin did not define the fittest as the strongest, or most clever, but recognized that the fittest could be those who cooperated with each other.

Comment: People who go on about genetic fitness but don't donate sperm are doing it wrong

Comment: @user18921 Although not holding the view that you described (I think), you may very well be interested in Binmore's [_Natural Justice_](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1705582).

Answer (score 1):

How can we predict what genetic success means, and for whom? For yourself, for the species, for life in general?

Morality is a characteristic of the human species as they are self-conscious creatures. As morality is pervasive amongst the human species one can posit that it is a species advantage. In the same way that for example language or music is.

Comment: Species-level selection has been known to be a very, very poor model of natural selection since at least the 1970's.

Comment: @user18921: I didn't say it was natural selection.

Comment: Oh. What notion of selection are you speaking of?

Comment: @user18921: There is more than one type of selective pressure. I said at the level of the species. You mentioned Natural selection which is at the level of the organism and I hadn't mentioned it.

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. How can you be sure that there's more than one level?